# Does last.fm add every song you play to your library?

Tags: music, last.fm

I might be insane, but a song played when I was listening to a neighborhood radio station. When I went to go look at my library later, the song showed up there. I don't own the song (or at least I didn't see it in my iTunes library under that name) and I don't think I've ever played it on my iPod or played it in iTunes or Windows Media Player from a friend's device. So I'm not sure why it would be there. Did I actually play it somewhere and have it scrobble or did listening to the song on the neighborhood radio add it to my library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listening to the song would have added it to your library. Think of your library as pretty much every song last.fm has counted as a "listen" or "scrobble".

How these scrobbles are counted depends on which client you use to listen to them with. For example, the last.fm desktop client has a setting that lets you decide how much of a song you need to listen to for it to count. I believe listening to a song on your iPod/iPhone will only count as a scrobble if the entire song was listened to (last time I checked this was because of restrictions in the iTunes API).

Comment: That's kind of silly, I think, but it does seem to account for what I've seen in my limited time with last.fm. I don't know why the service would put things I don't own into my library - to me, my library is music that I own and can listen to whenever I want.

Comment: you can 'add' music to your library without scrobbling it - meaning it'll consider you a listener of that artist/album/song even if you don't actually 'scrobble' it

Comment: My understanding that it adds the song & artist to your list, but you don't own it, with LastFM you can't request a particular song title to replay, you can select an artist, but there is no guarantee that a particular title will be played.

Comment: Scott: I know I don't actually own it, but I was expected my library to reflect only the songs that are on my computer that I do own, not every song that I listen to through their service.

Comment: @Thomas and @Scott: It's probably best to view the service as a way of exploring and discovering different music. If you are more interested in just listening to certain tracks there are other services (e.g. Spotify).

Comment: Alex: That's a good point. I think I was trying to use last.fm in a way it wasn't intended.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked this up, too. I'm not concerned with owning or not owning a song. But songs are showing my in my library that I haven't' even listened to! My library should only consist of songs I put there!